# Get Selected value from <ul> by Id in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `ul` which is `<ul>` list, I would like to get the selected value in different function and the list looks like below

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="ChooseAreaList">
   <li><a href="#">Select Destination</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">HSR</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Bommanahalli</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Kormangala</a></li>
</ul>
```

by applying some `CSS,JS` I am able to get selected value of list like this...

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
   var selText = $(this).text();///User selected value...****
   $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

but if i am trying to get this selected value in different function its not working...like this

```
function BusinessLogic(){
   var selText = $('.dropdown-menu li a').text();
   alert("Its displaying Entire List"+selText);
}
```

How to do I get selected value of that list in different function?

Comment: What about making a fiddle at jsfiddle.net to get proper response.

Comment: ul did not have a fixed selected, unless you assign a class to the li that you click, and clicking on another li will clear the class and reassign the class to the new li clicked, from there, you can based on the class to know that which li is being selected

Comment: you may use the function for this purpose, make one function that will return value of selected text and then call the first function into the 2nd function

Comment: @sharukh its a bad idea...:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put `class="selectedLi"` in `a` to indicate the last selected value from dropdown and use same as jquery selector in your `BusinessLogic` function :

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
      // remove previously added selectedLi
      $('.selectedLi').removeClass('selectedLi');
      // add class `selectedLi`
      $(this).addClass('selectedLi');
      var selText = $(this).text();///User selected value...****
      $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+
      ' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

And in below function use selectedLi in jquery selector :

```
function BusinessLogic()
{
 var selText = $('.dropdown-menu li a.selectedLi').text();

alert("Its displaying Entire List");

}
```

Comment: $('.dropdown-menu li.selectedLi  a').text() must be $('.dropdown-menu li a.selectedLi').text() because you are adding class to anchor not for li.

Comment: Hey what if i have two list...???for example City and area with same class,it will show the last selected element...:)\

Comment: Ok based on id i need to call the $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){ function like,$("#area li a").click(function(),$("#City li a").click(function(){

Comment: you can use different id for different list. Lets say `id="city"` and `id="area"`, and use these id as selector in jquery like `$("#city li a").click(function(){`

Comment: @goodyzain Good. yes, Like that you can grab that what you need

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var selText = $(.dropdown-menu li a).text();
```

to

```
var selText = $('.dropdown-menu li a').text();
```

**Update**: You need to add a class when a user selects something to distinguish from others

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
   var selText = $(this).text();///User selected value...****     
   $(this).addClass('active');
   $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

and in your other function do something like this:

```
function BusinessLogic(){
   var selText = $('.dropdown-menu li a.active').text();
   alert("Its displaying Entire List");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
   var selText = $(this).text();///User selected value...****
   //**$(".dropdown-menu li a").removeClass("select"); add this new**
   //**$(this).addclass('select'); add this new**
   $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});

====================


function BusinessLogic(){
       var selText = $(".select").text();
       alert("Its displaying Entire List");
}
```

Comment: you are adding `select` to `a` tag using `$(this).addclass('select');` and removing it from `li` elements `$(".dropdown-menu li").removeClass("select");`

Answer (score 0):

try this jsfiddle:-

```
$(".dropdown-menu").find("li a").click(function(){       
      $('.selectedLi').removeClass('selectedLi');     
      $(this).addClass('selectedLi'); 
});

$("#call").click(function(){
    BusinessLogic();
});

function BusinessLogic()
{ 
    var text = $('.dropdown-menu').find("li a.selectedLi").text(); 
    alert("selected Value:"+text);
}
```

[click here to see working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BtkCf/147/](http://jsfiddle.net/BtkCf/147/)